# Variable dentro de FOR - Java

Tags: java

Obtengo 0 en las variables *contAprobado* y *contSuspendido* al acabar el for. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener el resultado que acumulo en el for?

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
class NotaDeClase{
    private double nota;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setNota(){
        nota=sc.nextDouble();
    }

    public void notasClase(){

        int contSuspendido=0;
        int contAprobado=0;
        int i;

        for (i=0;i<3;i++){

            System.out.println("Introduce nota: ");
            setNota();

            if (nota>=5) contAprobado=contAprobado++;
            else     contSuspendido=contSuspendido++;

            while (nota>10 || nota<1){
                System.out.print("Nota invalida, introduce nota valida: ");
                setNota();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Nº APROBADOS: "+contAprobado);
        System.out.println("Nº SUSPENSOS: "+contSuspendido);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NotaDeClase a = new NotaDeClase();
        a.notasClase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo deja `contAprobado++` y  `contSuspendido++`. Eso sera suficiente para que el código funcione como quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias tío, ya lo solucioné, soy un principiante de esto jajaja ^^

Comment: Recuerda dar las gracias de manera constructiva, como marcando las respuestas como **Aceptadas✔**. Tal como se explica en el **[recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba Esto

```
contAprobado=contAprobado++;

contSuspendido=contSuspendido++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando escribes "++" a la derecha de una variable, estás ejecutando un POST-incremento. Esto significa que el incremento se efectua DESPUÉS de usar la variable.

Cuando haces contAprobado=contAprobado++ no estás haciendo nada. La variable se queda con el mismo valor que tenía. Esto es porque "contAprobado++" devuelve 0 (su valor previo), y posteriormente se incrementa, pero ese 0 lo estás guardando en la misma variable, por tanto, el resultado es que siempre se quede en su valor inicial, es decir, 0.

Tienes varias soluciones:

Ejecutar un PRE-incremento (primero efectúa el incremento, y después devuelve el valor de la variable):

```
contAprobado=++contAprobado;
```

Usar sencillamente, el postincremento:

```
contAprobado++;
```

O añadir 1 a la variable:

```
contAprobado += 1;
```